# Get ID's for each row from a select query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get each individual ID from the rows I queried with

```
$sql = "select child_id from enrollment where program_id='2';";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$numofkids = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "number of kids in baseball is $numofkids";

$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $array[0];
```

So the amount of kids registered in my baseball camp is 6 or 6 ID's come up when I do the select query or I mean 6 rows . so on the last 2 lines is my attempt on trying to extract the id's out of the query I made.
w/ this statement `echo $array[0];`, I successfully get the first id of the first child registered for baseball camp. But when I try to `echo $array[1];` to attempt to get the second id, I get nothing ? 
I know I'm doing something wrong but cant figure it out.

Comment: use var_dump($array); and print it

Comment: See loops or any one of the billion or so  examples out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code at place of the last two lines of your code

```
   while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo $array['child_id'];
   }
```

You have to take returned rows one by one and print them.

Comment: thanks so much saved from a world of headaches!

Comment: @thicksauce you are welcome and please vote it up